# PHP multiple image inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made code which every time user add image append another input for image.

It looks like this:

[image]

And this is code for that:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul class="add_img_ul">
        <li class="subimg"><input type="file" class="file" name="images[]" required multiple/><img class="add" src="icons/add.jpg" width="80px" height="80px"/></li>
    </ul>                       
<script>
    var inputLocalFont = document.querySelector(".file");
    inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

    function previewImages(){
        var fileList = this.files;

        var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
            var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
            $('.add_img_ul').append('<li class="subimg"><input type="file" class="file" name="images[]"/><img class="add_img" src="' + objectUrl + '" width="80px" height="80px"/></li>');
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
            }   
    }           


</script>
</form>
```

And my php code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['images'])){
    $number_of_file_fields = 0;
    $number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
    $number_of_moved_files = 0;
    $uploaded_files = array();
    $upload_directory = 'product_images';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++){
        $number_of_file_fields++;
        if($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != ''){
            $number_of_uploaded_files++;
            $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i])){
                $number_of_moved_files++;
            }
        }
    }

    $name = implode(',', $uploaded_files);
    echo $name;
}
```

Record of image path is stored into `$name`

When I run my code in `$name` is only one value, but when I add `required multiple` on one input then is good.

How can I store values from different inputs, but with same name into `$name`?

Thanks